# Problem with keyvalue pair when pulling field value in netSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Okay I'm having a really annoying thing I'm trying to debug. So, I have a function which iterates through a lot of items, and I'm having trouble with some of the items.

This is an example of an item I'm having trouble with. I have created a key value pair, which holds this:

```
var KeyValueobj = {
    "Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 0-3mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_03b2000w,
    "Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 0-3mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_03s2000w,
    "Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 0-3mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_03e2000w,

"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_412b2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_412s2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_412e2000w,

"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 >15mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_15b2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 >15mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_15s2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 >15mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_1403_15e2000w,

"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 >15mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_15b2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 >15mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_15s2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 >15mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_15e2000w,

"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 0-3mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_03b2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 0-3mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_03s2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 0-3mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_03e2000w,

"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 4-12mm >2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_412b2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 4-12mm <2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_412s2000w,
"Stainless steel plate EN 1.4401 4-12mm =2000mm wide": recordSetPricesItemObj.custrecordss_p_14401_412e2000w,
```

};
I'm searching through a record's fields in NetSuite and then I get their values and then pair those values with the correct field name.

I have created this test:

```
if (bomItem.displayname == "Stainless steel plate 1.4301/1.4307 t=10 EN 10088") {
    log.debug("CHECK1 : " + bomItem.custitem12)
    log.debug("CHECK2 : " + parseFloat(KeyValueobj["Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm >2000mm wide"]).toFixed(2))
    log.debug("CHECK3 : " + parseFloat(KeyValueobj[bomItem.custitem12]).toFixed(2))
    log.debug(bomItem.custitem12 == "Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm >2000mm wide")
}
Results:

check1 = "Stainless steel plate EN 1.4301 4-12mm >2000mm wide"
check2 = 26
check3 = NaN
check = false
```

This makes no sense in my head, why when I compare 2 identical strings they are not equal?

I have tried to check for whitespaces or test with regex and deleted all whitespaces then compared and still == false..

I have also tried this:

```
log.debug("CHECK6 : " + parseFloat(KeyValueobj[bomItem["custitem12"]]).toFixed(2));
```

I'm experiencing this bug on those display names. Can someone help?

I have tried using toString(), Stringify(), deleting all whitespaces with regex, tried to use normalize, also tried using unescape()

Comment: I don’t see any actual Suitescript in your samples. Where are you running this code?

Comment: This is a JS issue: Dump the value of KeyValueobj[bomItem.custitem12]. It is undefined most likely. You need to check if KeyValueobj[bomItem.custitem12], or any variable, is the type you expect before you even start using it....defensive coding